# Jersey takes empty String as a valid Integer value

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am trying to develop a sample REST API using Jersey

I have a following POJO Class

```
public class TestPOJOObject{

 String userName;
 int userId;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

I tried calling my API in two ways

1. With body `{"userName" : "Shiv" , "userId" : "abcd"}`

For this request Jersey throws the following error :

```
Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'abcd': not a valid Integer value
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@805f848; line: 1, column: 50] (through reference chain: com.sample.pojo.TestPOJOObject["useId"])
```

Which is perfectly fine.

2. When I try to call with body `{"userName" : "Shiv" , "userId" : " "}`

The api is executed successfully.  I monitored the value at the backed , for userId , it is '0'.

I am not able to understand , how the value for empty String is accepted and valued is assigned to '0'.

I want to understand what is happening in the back-end actually for this type of behaviour.

I am using Jersey 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used primitive int for userId , library converts the value to 0 if it is empty. If you use the wrapper Integer, you would get null as the value.